# does hadoop 2.2.0 active namenode delete edit logs?

Tags: logging, hadoop, edit, high-availability

When i open ${dfs.namenode.name.dir},there was a log of edits_* files, and seems not auto deleted by namenode, so should i delete edit logs checked manually ?
And also ${dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir} seems became bigger and bigger.

Comment: In fact I am looking for the answer for same question.
If i understand correctly the properties used (dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained & dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained)is to retain particular number of transaction which might require during the run time. So does it mean the edits created at initial stage will be auto deleted from the namenode? Please correct me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.I've find configuration in hdfs.xml as followed:
dfs.namenode.num.extra.edits.retained & dfs.namenode.num.checkpoints.retained